# Operation is not valid for the state of the transaction LINQ to SQL ExecuteCommand

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, transactionscope

So I have the following code:

```
var transactionScopeOptions = new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) };
            using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionScopeOptions))
            {

/* Linq update, insert, delete, read, etc. */


protected const string UpdateQuery = @"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
                             BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                             /* dirty reads & 3 table updates */

                             COMMIT TRANSACTION;"

   dataContext.ExecuteCommand(UpdateQuery, new object[] { fooID, fooTime })
   transactionScope.Complete();
            }
```

Where at first, I don't do Linq to Sql string queries, then in one class, I used a very long string query to update 3 tables. This is the part where I get the exception. (in ExecuteCommand)

The environment is WCF multithreading, there is a log for the the time when an item starts and another log when the item ends, it is not a timeout exception.

I processing more than hundreds of thousands of items with concurrency set to multiple.

Any idea why the exception is being thrown? The dataContext is only instantiated once per item.

**EDIT:** Command Timeout is set to 1 hour, and the error happens in a few minutes from starting. It usually doesn't happen if there are less than 100,000 items in the queue.

**EDIT:** stacktrace:

> at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction
>   tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
>   at
>   System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification
>   promotableSinglePhaseNotification)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal&amp; connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser
>   user)    at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteCommand(String
>   command, Object[] parameters)

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: There, just added the stacktrace..

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning off connection pooling in the connection string, i have noticed that connections seem to be returned to the pool before the distributed transaction the SQL operation has enlisted in via IIS has committed or rolled back. Although the symptoms for this are ussaly a connection timeout, but it might be worth a try.

ADD "pooling=false;" to your connection string